# How to find one specific column of matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

$A$ is a square $n \times n$ invertible matrix, where $n$ is around $1000$. Is there any efficient way to compute only the $i$-th column of $A^{-1}$? Or is it better to calculate the whole matrix inverse?

Comment: Form the augmented matrix $[\mathrm A \mid \mathrm e_i]$ and use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo is there any notable difference between Gaussian and Gauss Jordan? What is the time complexity by that approach?

Comment: You have a linear system $\mathrm{A x} = \mathrm{e}_i$. Use whatever method you like.